# Copying data from one table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I'm updating data by selecting data from table and inserting into another. However there are some constraints on the other table and I get this :

```
DETAIL:  Key (entry_id)=(391) is duplicated.
```

I basically do  this :

```
insert into table_tmp 
select * from table_one
```

How can I skip insert when this key entry duplicate occurs?

Update I can't save this schema info on SQL fiddle but here it is :

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    ("entry_id" int, "text" varchar(255))
;

INSERT INTO table1
    ("entry_id", "text")
VALUES
    (1, 'one'),
    (2, 'two'),
    (3, 'test'),
    (3, 'test'),
    (12, 'three'),
    (13, 'four')
;



CREATE TABLE table2
    ("entry_id" int, "text" varchar(255))
;

Create unique index entry_id_idxs
on table2 (entry_id)
where text='test';

INSERT INTO table2
    ("entry_id", "text")
VALUES
    (1, 'one'),
    (2, 'two'),
    (3, 'test'),
    (3, 'test'),
    (12, 'three'),
    (13, 'four')
;
```

Error that I get if I try to build the schema

Comment: Are you creating unique index with `WHERE` constraint? Why? It does not make any sense. Please remove `WHERE` from index creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert using join that returns unmatched rows:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.entry_id = t1.entry_id
WHERE t2.entry_id IS NULL
```

Comment: thanks for the answer Bohemian, this time I'm getting another error :
`ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "entry_id_idx"`

Comment: I added the `DISTINCT` keyword - see if that helps. btw, your example won't build (on sqlfiddle) because table2 is starting out with duplicates - you need to remove one of the id=3 inserts into table2. also add a different value to table1 to make the example make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Use this query - [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/77e07/3):

```
INSERT INTO table2 
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT entry_id
    FROM table2 t2
    WHERE t2.entry_id = t1.entry_id
)
```

Comment: This query will work fast as long as there is an index on `entry_id` in both tables

Comment: From checking the web I belive postgres behaves equal for both cases. I'm sorry I'm not a postgres man myself! http://explainextended.com/2009/09/16/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-postgresql/

Comment: Thanks for the answer mvp, I also get the same error as from bohemians query : `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "entry_id_idx"`

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow: I don't understand how is this possible. My SQLFiddle is most certainly working as expected - it skips duplicate keys. Are you sure that you are telling the whole story? Can you provide some smaller sanitized example which does not work for you?

Comment: Yes I guess we wrote comments at the same time, I updated my question. Your fiddle is working but I guess I didn't ask the question accurately so I've updated it now. I can't(don't know how to) update the fiddle because the schema is not building.thanks

Comment: Your updated example has partial unique index - this does not make any sense. Please remove WHERE from index creation, and it should work. Also, your example has duplicate row with `(3, 'test')` for insert - it is also going to cause constraint violation

Comment: Where is because I want to get rid of the duplicate records from table one and copy them over into new table